# Query to return non identical rows in two tables with same schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been doing a bit of searching for a while now on a particular problem, but I can't quite find this particular question

I have a rather unusual task to achieve in SQL:

I have two tables, say A and B, which have exactly the same column names, of the following form:

id | column_1 | ... | column_n

Both tables have the same number of rows, with the same id's, but for a given id there is a chance that the rows from tables A and B differ in one or more of the other columns.

I want a query which returns all rows from table A for which the corresponding row in table B is not identical.

Suppose
Table A
|ID  |C_ID  | FName | Phone | Email |Title            |
|:---|-----:|------:|------:|------:|-----------------|
|28  | abc  | xyz   |50925  |19080  |software engineer|
|29  | def  |  mno  |50926  |19081  |software engineer|
|30  | def  |  pqr  |50927  |19082  |software engineer|

Table B
|ID  |C_ID  | FName | Phone | Email |Title            |
|:---|-----:|------:|------:|------:|-----------------|
|28  | abc  | xyz   |50925  |19080  |software engineer|
|29  | def  |  mno  |50926  |19081  |Data Analyst     |
|30  | def  |  pqr  |6000   |19082  |software engineer|

The result should be:
|ID  |C_ID  | FName | Phone | Email |Title            |
|:---|-----:|------:|------:|------:|-----------------|
|29  | def  |  mno  |50926  |19081  |Data Analyst     |
|30  | def  |  pqr  |6000   |19082  |software engineer|

The value in phone and title is not matching with previous values. I need  the query which will return the records which got updated.

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-minus/

Answer (score 0):

Use `MINUS`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_a
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table_b
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (id, column1, column2) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b (id, column1, column2) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/53qPmHmi)

Comment: @MuktaDiware Don't try to explain in comments (because it did not make sense); [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74112229/edit) and give us a complete [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; a complete explanation of the logic you want to implement; and the expected output for your sample data.